Requesting information regarding citizenship by ancestry
My paternal grandfather was a Dutch citizen who immigrated to America when he was 18.  My maternal and paternal great grand parents were Dutch citizens who migrated to America.
Does this Dutch ancestry on both my maternal and paternal sides make becoming a Dutch citizen any easier for me?  I'm American.

Did any of your parents hold Dutch citizenship?

This depends highly on when these things happened, as well as on the timing of any of your Dutch ancestors' naturalization.  One possible scenario in which I believe you may already be Dutch: your father reached his 18th birthday before your paternal grandfather naturalized, he moved to an EU country after April 1st 2004 but before his 27th birthday, and you were born after April 1st 1994.  There are many possibilities, most of which are probably somewhat remote, but without these kinds of details it's difficult to say much of anything useful.

@o.m. presumably if they did, neither they nor Marcia were aware of it.  This is fairly common in these cases; for example my father thought he had lost his Dutch nationality when he naturalized in the US, but he hadn't because he was 19, and at the time the age of majority in Dutch law was still 21.
